# Clearcase activities

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-remote-client

I am new to clearcase so i would like to remove the baselined activities(i.e., already done activities) in my view any there any command is available to remove them or is it possible to remove them in Windows GUI.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to make those activities "invisibles", that is:

- right click on an activity
- go to the "lock" tab
- make it "obsolete" (nobody will see that activity again or will be able to select it for a checkout/checkin operation)

But that will work only if you are the owner (creator) of the activity you are locking obsolete.
(See [activity states](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.doc/topics/u_props_activity.htm) and [`cleartool lock`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lock.htm), the API command behind that GUI operation)

Comment: What is the command in linux ? 
Lets say that the activity name is alex_tst

Comment: @user3502786 `cleartool lock -obs activity:alex_tst@/vobs/yourPVob`

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove an activity already included in a baseline. You will need to remove the baseline first, then remove the activity from the stream.